# How can I set the distance from last row to the end of DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How can I set the distance from last row to the end of DataGridView ?
My last row stay at the end of DataGridView ,  so i want to have last row at the top of the DataGridView ,
and I want increase the distance between last row and the end of DataGridView .

[this image explains what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzA0f.png)

[I can do that with panel by AutoScrollMargin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KrPj.jpg)

Comment: So only one row? Or you just want the last row to be at the tip of the arrow at top where your wanted line is?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Also - please only include a tag for the language that you're using - a lot of users ignore questions with tags that they don't specialize in. Thanks